# Uber China estimate fare mismatch with real app

Tags: uber-api

Am in the middle of using uber api(Mobile) to get the estimated fare for china region.

Am using Baidu map to get the coordinate between From: 龙居大厦
 To: 虹桥火车站-地铁站. So my request to get estimate price becomes:

https://api.uber.com.cn/v1/estimates/price?start_latitude=31.263004&start_longitude=121.565063&end_latitude=31.192377&end_longitude=121.334137&server_token=R52QOQyjVVqgCqds1hVxTtyT7YSRjNZY6qP4Dcnz

```
Response: {
    "currency_code" = CNY;
    "display_name" = "People's Uber +";
    distance = "17.61";
    duration = 2880;
    estimate = "CN\U00a574-99";
    "high_estimate" = 99;
    "localized_display_name" = "People's Uber +";
    "low_estimate" = 74;
    minimum = 13;
    "product_id" = "c9ded892-05bf-4efb-8056-3301bc65a3e7";
    "surge_multiplier" = 1; }, 
    {
    "currency_code" = CNY;
    "display_name" = "Shared Ride";
    distance = "17.61";
    duration = 2880;
    estimate = "CN\U00a575.84";
    "high_estimate" = 76;
    "localized_display_name" = "Shared Ride";
    "low_estimate" = 75;
    minimum = "<null>";
    "product_id" = "74d2f8af-5027-4d42-960e-bc879f8ea54b";
    "surge_multiplier" = 1; }, etc (ignoring uberx, uber sedan, UberXl)
```

problem is estimated price is mismatching with real app fare (Added link for screenshot. [Uber real app fare screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ0fs.jpg)). So Can someone please help me in clearing below doubt.

1. Is my request is correct to get the estimated price.
2. Why Uber API response fare is mismatching compared to real app.
3. How uber calculates the single price and uses "&UP", using the high and low estimated price.

Waiting for your speedy response. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1) The difference between the two estimates can be explained as we use different signals when providing an estimate (v1/estimates/price) vs providing an upfront fare id (/v1/requests/estimates).

To request a fare_id (which has the most accurate fare) see the docs for /v1/requests/estimates - https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post

The v1 price estimates endpoint does not always reflect promotions that may be available in the local market. This is resolved in the v1.2 endpoint:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get

I would recommend upgrading to v1.2 to resolve the issue with /v1/estimates/price or if this is for an authenticated user provide an upfront fare with /v1.2/requests/estimate.

---

I also wanted to confirm you know we are *shutting down* the .cn API on November 29th.